# How to install the gedmo-extensions in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, orm, tree, doctrine-orm, behavior

i'm trying to install the ["gedmo" behaviourial extensions (version 2.1.0-DEV)](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) in Doctrine2 (version 2.1.3).

Without the extensions everything works fine. However, when I add the annotationdriver to read the @gedmo-annotations errors such as "`Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class User2 is not a valid entity or mapped super class`" are thrown.
This is de User2-entity:

```
<?php

use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity  */
class User2 {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=255) */
    private $username;
}
```

Because these errors occur even in the Entities where @gemdo is not used i suspect it has something to do with the way the annotationdrivers are configured. In my bootstrap-file the annotation driver is added (i'm only going to use the tree-extension):

```
$reader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();
$annotationDriver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver($reader);

$chain = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain;
$chain->addDriver($annotationDriver, 'Gedmo\Tree\Entity');

$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($chain);
```

A few questions:

1. Should I add a driver for the ORM-annotation?
2. Is there something wrong with the User2-class?
3. How can I get a more specific user-error enabling me to find the exact cause of the problem?

In short: how can I make the @orm and @gedmo annotations work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was recently an [example](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/example) added in order to show how to configure bare entity manager with extensions whithout any framework used.
You can follow the [readme](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/README.md) at the bottom on how to setup it initially